# Why am I recieing a FALSE value instead of Specified Value on IF statement?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to assign each cell to a type based on what value they hold

The D83 value changes, for example, if I put D83 with a value of 4 I will get the value TYPE A, also when I put a value of 60 or above I get TYPE C. The problem is that when I type a value between 30-59 or value 30 or 59, I always get FALSE instead of TYPE B. Appreciate the help!

Current code/formula:

```
=if(D83<=29,"TYPE A", if(D83="30-59","TYPE B" , if(D83>=60, "TYPE C" )))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you should do it:

```
=IF(D83<=29,       "TYPE A", 
 IF(AND(D83=>30, 
        D83 <60"), "TYPE B" , 
 IF(D83>=60,       "TYPE C" , )))
```

---

alternatives: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Answer (score 0):

There is already a correct answer, but also bear in mind that you can simplify the logic a bit

```
=If(D83<=29,"Type A",if(D83<=59,"Type B","Type C"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX("TYPE "&{"A","B","C"},MATCH(D83,{0,30,60},1))
```

- `MATCH` to find the range D83 falls in
- `INDEX` to return appropriate type